# Pass value from a form to another component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have an input field where the user enters a name, and I then want this name to be display at all times on the navbar. After entering a name the user presses a button that takes them to a new screen via `react-router-dom` like this

`<Link to="/events">
       <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </Link>`

This is what I have right now

In my component with the input field

```
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {value: ''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        console.log(this.state);
      }

      handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
      }

    render() {
        return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="email"
            className="form-control"
            id="inputEmail3"
            placeholder="Enter your username"
            onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        )
    }
}
```

I removed anything that doesn't have to do with the particular input field, which is why the return statement looks the way it does.

With what I have now, I get the input field value as a state, but I'm not sure how to get that value in another component.

I then have a Navbar component where I have a simple `<p className="">Username</p>` where I want the name to be displayed.

Any help on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can I see your React Router code? How do you redirect?

Comment: Here it is: `<Link to="/events">
                     <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign 
                         in</button>
                  </Link>`

Comment: `<Link to={{pathname:'/events', state: { username: ... }}>` then in the new page use `this.props.location.state.username`

Comment: I'm sorry but this is still a bit unclear to me. I want the username to end up in the navbar, so it's not actually on the 'events' page that I'm redirecting to. I have my navbar as a component.